# IP Address Restriction in Bonsai ElasticSearch as a Heroku Addon

Tags: heroku, elasticsearch

I have started using Heroku's addon for ElasticSearch, Bonsai.  I want to create a backend search for several categories on my website.  Since this is a backend only service, and may contain sensitive information, how do I limit the IP addresses connecting to the Bonsai server that Heroku has provided me to only the IP address/range of my web servers.

Note that my web servers are running on private hardware and are not hosted on a cloud service.  I am also not using any other web service on Heroku, so I prefer not to use a Ruby answer to this.

Comment: You should definitely get in touch with me at info@bonsai.io if you haven't already so we can discuss that. We've got options for you.

Comment: Ok, I have sent you an email.  And, thanks for looking into this.

Comment: For anyone that ends up here from Google... What was the answer/solution?

Comment: @Nick we've got a pretty robust HTTPS + Basic Auth support, and IP whitelisting on a beta basis. For posterity, if unclear, drop us a line and we're happy to work with you on a variety of auth use cases.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up working with the Bonsai team to set up a custom solution on their end that required a username and password combination to access any data on my hosted search.