# ElasticSearch restrict access using IP tables

Tags: linux, security, elasticsearch, iptables

I have seen a couple of dead threads like this

[IP Address Restriction in Bonsai ElasticSearch as a Heroku Addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510103/ip-address-restriction-in-bonsai-elasticsearch-as-a-heroku-addon)

and this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121531/tomcat-restrict-ip-access-ip-range-format

This is the first time I have hosted an ElasticSearch server to a linux machine . Let's assume my ES server is located at `http://161.241.117.47:9200` and I have an app server at 161.241.117.41

Question is what can I do with my ip tables so that http requests to 161.241.117.47:9200 are only catered if they come from 161.241.117.41

Also, is there a possibility of creating a rule in iptable based on ethernet address? So I can connect from my latptop using HTTP?

I know I can use something like following

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9200 -j ACCEPT
```

But this will allow all incoming connections.

When I used the suggestions from the following answer it worked correctly with one IP but didn't for two!
My iptable currently looks like this and is not able to filter multiple IPs

```
 INPUT ACCEPT [554:135189]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3207:497908]
-A INPUT -s 182.72.29.250/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9200:9400 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 162.243.225.24/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9200:9400 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9200:9400 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First, you need to set which IP's that can reach the computer

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 9200:9400 -s IP_ADRRESS_1,IP_ADRRESS_2,IP_ADRRESS_3 -j ACCEPT
```

Then, you need to restrict any ip except specified ones can reach your ports.

```
iptables -I INPUT 4 -p tcp --dport 9200:9400 -j REJECT
```

Finally save your settings to a file.

```
sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules"
```

If you want these changes persists on reboots, execute `sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces` and add following `pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules`

***Few things to remember:***

1. You can add more ips to first command.
2. If you add extra ips you should set the value(4) in the second command. It is the rule order, so it must be latest rule. Thus add 1 for each ip you add.

Comment: Does that mean if I have only two IPs then second command will have 2?  Also anyway we can restrict access via ethernet address?

Comment: if you have two IPs second command will have 3(if you dont have any other IP tables settings). For your second question, i dont have the answer :(

Comment: Hey, What is the meaning of 9400?

Comment: It worked for single IP but when I did multiple IPs it is not working. Any idea? I have updated my question to show the latest IPTABLE

Comment: It disables from 9200 to 9400. Since defaulty elasticsearch uses these ports.

Comment: so, what is the current situation? With above settings you can be able to reach the server 9200-9400 from only those two IPs.

Comment: Well, I tried to access it form 182.72.29.250 but I could not. Neither telnet nor elasticsearch. I finally ended flusing the tables

Comment: -I INPUT 4 <-- why 4? What does that stand for?

Comment: @HenleyChiu it is the order of the rule. rule 1 IP_1, rule 2 IP_2, rule 3 IP_3 and rule 4 is REJECT whats left.

Comment: dont forget add 127.0.0.1 to the ip list